Centos Firewalld - Disable logging for a single role
Been through the firewalld documentation trying to figure out how not to log rejected packets for a single rule.  I have a host that keeps trying to connect to my Centos machine.  The log file on the server gets very large due to the numerous 'denied' attempts.  I just want to suppress these rejects but want to see denied logs for all others.  I'm using rich rules and editing the public zone xml file to add rules.  I only see on/off logging choices at higher level places, and only severity (categorization) levels at the rules level.  I saw several options but not the disabled choice.
Reading the docs, it sounded like I could put the individual drop rule in the file. And then it would not drop the log entry. I could go the the source host and block the outbound packet but would only go that way as a last resort.
Best regards.
Jo
